# Vuejs v-for is working but I can't call local variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, hapi

I have a simple html called in hapi back end:

```
<form id="databinding" action="/config/update" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <select v-model="extensions.listType" style="width:300px;font-size:25px;">
      <option value="authorized">Inclusion list</option>
      <option value="forbidden">Exclusion list</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(ext, index) in extensions[extensions.listType]"
        :key="index"
        onclick="console.log(ext)"
      >
        {{ext}}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button type="submit">Save parameters</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#databinding",
    data() {
      return {
        maxBytes: 5000000,
        extensions: {
          listType: "forbidden",
          forbidden: ["bat", "bin", "chm", "class", "com", "dll"],
          authorized: ["3g2", "3gp", "arf", "asf"]
        }
      };
    }
  });
</script>
```

the *v-for* element displays the right number of dots but with nothing written with it (see picture). When I log the *ext* variable, I get "ext is not defined". I tried the same thing with *extensions*.
It seems like vue's data is ok in the *v-for* statement, but not after that.

Does someone has an idea of what's happening, I'm running out of solutions.
[result of the *v-for* statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJogO.png)

## EDIT

Solved the issue, I just needed to add webpack to render the template

Comment: what version of vue are you using? it seems to be working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ytcjqnv/). use `@click` instead of `onclick` and don't call `console.log` from the html

Comment: replace your onClick with @click and try again. Any errors in the console.

Comment: I tested your code and it works with cottect title in the list

Comment: maybe they are styled as white color and you can't see them

Comment: console.log to vue data property will not work here. the reason is you use native onclick and not @click. so vue wont translate the ext to real ext. vue only treat v-bind and v-on (and the shorthands of them). the remain parts of your code is working correctly

Comment: It's really strange, it must have something to do with vue version, or the way I import vue maybe ...

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki it is not white, I can see what is written in the developer's console

Comment: @HBDD see my answer. It has nothing to do with styling and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `@click` handler of vuejs. Now you can call the external function from the method in vuejs. Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/v08i/pen/xxGVQRE

```
function logThisExternal(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

new Vue({
  el: '#databinding',
    data () {
    return {
       extensions: {
          listType: "forbidden",
          forbidden: ["bat", "bin", "chm", "class", "com", "dll"],
          authorized: ["3g2", "3gp", "arf", "asf"]
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logThis: function(ext) {
      logThisExternal(ext);
    }
  }
})
```

Template code:

```
<form id="databinding" action="/config/update" method="post">
 <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(ext, index) in extensions[extensions.listType]"
        :key="index"
        @click="logThis(ext)"
      >
        {{ext}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Note that I have created a function `logThisExternal` which is being called from the vuejs method `logThis`

Comment: the issue is not related to the @click handler. I added when I tried to understand the issue, the problem was that I was not rendering properly the template.